# Electron spawn ffmpeg ENOENT

Tags: ffmpeg, electron

I am building an Electron app to display a rtsp stream.

When using the locally installed ffmpeg (/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg) on the (MacOS) Desktop all works well. Since the app needs to be distributed to different desktops and i don't want to be dependent on local installation of ffmpeg i am trying to bundle ffmpeg / fluent-ffmpeg but somehow i am missing the clue and all my attempts end up in Uncaught Error: spawn ffmpeg ENOENT

I am a complete newby to Electron and nodejs and am sure i am missing a very basic concept here, somebody willing to help me out?

This is my code:

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },
  });
    
  win.loadFile('index.html');
};

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self' ws://localhost:9993; script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; "
    />
    
    <title>RTSP viewer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-sm"><h2>RTSP stream</h2><canvas class="canvas" id="canvas3"></canvas></div>

    </body>

    <script src='./jsmpeg.min.js'></script>
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
    
</html>
```

preload.js

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

const ffmpegPath = require("@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg").path;
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

var stream = require('node-rtsp-stream')

stream3 = new stream({
    name: 'stream3',
    streamUrl: 'rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/...........',
    wsPort: 9993,
    ffmpegOptions: {

  }
})
```

renderer.js

```
const player = new JSMpeg.Player('ws://localhost:9993', {
      canvas: document.getElementById('canvas3'), audio: false
    })
```